# How to answer the logcat below?

Tags: android

Anybody here please help me to check on this LogCat, what is exactly error? After I click on Button it's alway appear error, event I tried to fix it many times.

```
11-26 20:49:24.143: W/dalvikvm(436): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion/kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion.animal_q_easy_3}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion.animal_q_easy_3.onCreate(animal_q_easy_3.java:75)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  ... 11 more
```

## My Activity

```
public class animal_q_easy_3 extends Activity {

//SQLite Method
private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

private ImageView play_home, play_now, play_again;

private TextView get_text_1, get_text_2, title, top_answer_ab;

private TextView score = null;
private int correct = 0;
private CountDownTimer aCounter = null;

TextView timer, l_timer;

private Button tiger, chicken, bee, pig;
private Button tiger_t, chicken_t, bee_t, pig_t;

private TextView ti, ch, be, pi;
private TextView ti_txt, ch_txt, be_txt, pi_txt;

Dialog myDialog;

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "SimpleDateFormat" })
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int screen = (int) rnd.nextInt(3)+1;

    switch(screen)
    {
        case 1:
            setContentView(R.layout.animal_q_easy_3);
        break;
        case 2:
            setContentView(R.layout.animal_q_easy_3_a);
        break;
        case 3:
            setContentView(R.layout.animal_q_easy_3_b);
        break;
    }

    ti = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ti); ti.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ch); ch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    be = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.be); be.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pi); pi.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ti_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ti_txt); ti_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ch_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ch_txt); ch_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    be_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.be_txt); be_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pi_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pi_txt); pi_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //Hide Play Again, Go Home Button
    final RelativeLayout top_answer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.top_answer);
    //top_answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final RelativeLayout gameEnd = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_ended);
    gameEnd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    play_home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_home);
    play_home.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    play_again = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_again);
    play_again.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    play_now = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_now);
    play_now.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final MediaPlayer failAnswer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fail_buzzer);
    final MediaPlayer welldone = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.welldone);
    final MediaPlayer yousosmart = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yousosmart);
    final MediaPlayer yousogood = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yousogood);
    final MediaPlayer win = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.win_sound);
    final MediaPlayer ohmygod = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ohmygod);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    top_answer_ab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tittop_answer_ab);
    top_answer_ab.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    get_text_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.get_text_1);
    get_text_1.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    get_text_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.get_text_2);
    get_text_2.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    score.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));

    tiger = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiger);
    tiger.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    tiger.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.memory_cover);

    chicken = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chicken);
    chicken.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    chicken.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.memory_cover);

    bee = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bee);
    bee.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    bee.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.memory_cover);

    pig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pig);
    pig.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    pig.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.memory_cover);

    tiger_t = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tiger_t);
    tiger_t.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    tiger_t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.memory_cover);

    chicken_t = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chicken_t);
    chicken_t.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    chicken_t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.memory_cover);

    bee_t = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bee_t);
    bee_t.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    bee_t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.memory_cover);

    pig_t = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pig_t);
    pig_t.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
    pig_t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.memory_cover);

  //Timer
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    l_timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.l_timer);
    aCounter = new CountDownTimer(32000, 1000)
    {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            timer.setText("" +new SimpleDateFormat("ss").format(new Date(millisUntilFinished)));

            if((millisUntilFinished / 1000)<=10 )
            {
                timer.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                failAnswer.start();
            }
        }

        public void onFinish()
        {
            ohmygod.start();
            timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            l_timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            title.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            RelativeLayout gameEnd = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_ended);
            gameEnd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            play_home.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            play_again.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            tiger.setVisibility(View.GONE); tiger_t.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            chicken.setVisibility(View.GONE); chicken_t.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bee.setVisibility(View.GONE); bee_t.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pig.setVisibility(View.GONE); pig_t.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            top_answer_ab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            top_answer_ab.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            top_answer_ab.setText("Time's up! You failed!");
            //Insert into DB
            mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(animal_q_easy_3.this);
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

            // Data del trov insert
            String level = "Easy";
            String failed = "Fail";
            int A = 0;
            int B = 0;
            int level_step_b = 0;
            int percentage = 0;

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm");
            String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

            mySQLiteAdapter.insert_ANIMAL(level, A, B, formattedDate, percentage, failed, level_step_b);

            mySQLiteAdapter.close();
        }
     };
     aCounter.start();
```

Comment: what is line 75 `animal_q_easy_3.java`?. Something on that line is null

Comment: Can you please post your activity onCreate?

Comment: when I click on button it's will call this activity animal_q_easy_3.java to start.. and this animal_q_easy_3.java already created.

Comment: you are getting null pointer error, something you are retrieving null value..

Comment: I have put my activity. please check sirs.

Comment: @SopheakVirak line 75 pls.

Comment: @Raghunandan, here is like 75: ti = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ti); ti.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: @SopheakVirak ti is null check the id in xml

Comment: How come you have the same View Ids regardless of the loaded layout?

Comment: Oh..my god, thank you Raghunandan, I got it now, bcoz I have 3 xml and I random it..but other 2 of layout ID is difference. Thank again Raghunandan, You save my time now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, your id is not as per the setContentview(based on a switch case statement), so when you call

```
ti = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ti); ti.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

it is not able to identify `R.id.ti` and hence the `NullPointerException`

Check that you are calling the correct ids based on the layout selected from `switch` statement

Comment: Line 75 will be different in the actual file, because package statement and import statements will present at the top, so the line number is not same as the block of code shared in the question

Comment: I agree, but as you see the statement mentioned by him is in the very beginning of the `onCreate()`. So, you can assume that he has already considered package and import statements. He wouldn't have counted it manually, obviously he might be using an IDE which is giving a true picture, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

this is your error

`11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 20:49:24.173: E/AndroidRuntime(436):  at kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestion.animal_q_easy_3.onCreate(animal_q_easy_3.java:75)`

`75` here denotes the line number where the error occured. please post the code of that line and for future always search for this type of line in the log consisting of `caused by` and followed by your `Class` name.